# If $G$ is solvable and acts such that $\mbox{fix}(g) \in \{0,p\}$ for $g \ne 1$ and $M$ is maximal normal. Then $|G/M| = p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a transitive permutation group on $\Omega$ which fulfills the following property (P)

> (P) each nontrivial element fixes no point or exactly $p$ points.

for some odd prime $p$. Further suppose that for $g \notin N_G(G_{\alpha})$ we have
$$
 G_{\alpha} \cap G_{\alpha}^g = 1
$$
for some point stabilizer $G_{\alpha}$ and that $p$ is the smallest prime dividing the order of $G$. Assume $G$ to be solvable and that $M$ is a maximal intransitive normal subgroup. We have $|G / M| = q$ where $q$ is prime.

So $M$ has $q$ orbits and $M_{\alpha} = G_{\alpha}$. Let $\Delta$ be the orbit of $M$ containing $\alpha$ and suppose $\Delta$ contains all $p$ fixed points of $G_{\alpha}$. Then $M$ in its action on $\Delta$ and the other orbits has property (P). Further $M$ can have at most $p+1$ representations as a group which has the property (P) with mutually disjoint point stabilizers.

> Why does the property that $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ implies that $q = p$? And why can $M$ have at most $p+1$ representations as a group with property (P)?

I cannot connect the number $p+1$ of representations to the conlusion that $q = p$. Hopeing someone could clarify this!?

Comment: So $M$ has at most $p+1$ orbits. Are you assuming that $p$ is odd? Otherwise $p=2$, $q=3$ could be possible.

Comment: Yes, $p$ is odd. Sorry, I edited my post!

Comment: Then I don't see the problem. $p+1 \le q \Rightarrow p=q$.

Comment: Yes, but why we have only $p+1$ representations? Where does this bound comes from?

Comment: That wasn't what you asked about! It looks like a counting argument. If you had more than $p+1$ such disjoint subgroups, their union would have size larger than $|G|$.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that. I edited the text. You mean subgroups of $M$, as such a representation is realised as an action on cosets of $M$? But why they have to be disjoint then?

Comment: The statement I thought you were asking about assumes that they are mutually disjoint. I am really unsure what it is that you do not understand!

Comment: Okay, I though arbitrary representation, but it seems to mean representation on the fixed set $\Omega$. So each action on an $M$-orbit could be represented as an action on the cosets of a point stabilizer, so the number of different point stabilizers gives an upper bound on the number of different representations. Yes, by assumption they have trivial intersection. So they contain $|G : N_G(G_{\alpha})|(|G_{\alpha}| - 1) + 1$ elements, and if we have more than $p+1$ we would have at least $k := (p+2)(|G_{\alpha}| - 1) + 1$ elements in $G$. Is ths right, now I need to derive that $k > |G|$?

Comment: These are conjugacy classes of subgroups, and each such conjugacy class consists of $|\Omega|/p$ disjoint subgroups. Sorry, but that's my last comment on this!